# How to check values is zero inside DataRow

Tags: c#, list, datarow, divide-by-zero

In my code, I'm adding a list to values inside the `foreach` by iterating `DataRow`. My code as follows,

```
ActivityUserResult Result = new ActivityUserResult();
Result.TransacDetails = new List<TransactionStatistics>();
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[2].Rows)
{
    Result.TransacDetails.Add(new TransactionStatistics()
    {
        Id = Convert.ToString(row["Id"]),,
        AssistCount = Convert.ToInt32(row["AssistCount"]),
        WaitTime = Convert.ToInt32(row["WaitTime"]),
        AverageStandardWaitTime = (Convert.ToInt32(row["WaitTime"]) / Convert.ToInt32(row["AssistCount"])) / 60                    
    });
}
```

I need to get `AverageStandardWaitTime` value by dividing `WaitTime` by `AssistCount`.  To do that I added this inside loop

```
AverageStandardWaitTime = (Convert.ToInt32(row["WaitTime"]) / Convert.ToInt32(row["AssistCount"])) / 60
```

But sometimes `AssistCount` value will be Zero. So I'm getting this error.

```
System.DivideByZeroException: 'Attempted to divide by zero.'
```

How can I check if `AssistCount` value is Zero? if not zero I need to divide and otherwise I need to avoid the dividing and need to set `AverageStandardWaitTime` value as 0

Comment: Why not simply use an if statement if (Convert.ToInt32(row["AssistCount"]) != 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ternary operator for this which is pretty straightforward:

```
AverageStandardWaitTime = (Convert.ToInt32(row["AssistCount"]) > 0 
                            ? Convert.ToInt32(row["WaitTime"]) / Convert.ToInt32(row["AssistCount"]) 
                            : 0)
```

you can make it better by reusing the converted values if want to instead of converting the value every time.

```
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[2].Rows)
{
    Result.TransacDetails.Add(new TransactionStatistics()
    {
        Id = Convert.ToString(row["Id"]),,
        AssistCount = Convert.ToInt32(row["AssistCount"]),
        WaitTime = Convert.ToInt32(row["WaitTime"]),
        AverageStandardWaitTime = (Convert.ToInt32(row["WaitTime"]) > 0 
                                   ? (Convert.ToInt32(row["WaitTime"]/Convert.ToInt32(row["AssistCount"]))/60 
                                   :  Convert.ToInt32(row["WaitTime"])
                                  )                   
    });
}
```

Comment: How can I return value with 2 decimal points? because when the waittime is 0 its return only zero without decimal points I need 0.00

Comment: when "WaitTime":32, and AssistCount = 2 , AverageStandardWaitTime is showing as 0 can you please tell me why

Comment: can you debug and see what are the actual values and use quick watch to find which expression is causing issue

Answer (score 1):

you can create function and then give call to it for, this way you can have clear code and proper message about some went wrong with data

```
public double CalculateAverageStandardWaitTime(DataRow row)
{
  int waitTime = Convert.ToInt32(row["WaitTime"];
  int assistcount =  Convert.ToInt32(row["AssistCount"]);
  if(assistcount != 0 ) {
    return (Convert.ToInt32(row["WaitTime"]) / 
         Convert.ToInt32(row["AssistCount"])) / 60;
  }
  else {
   //log message that value is less then zeor 
   //return some defautl value 
   return -1; //0 
  }
}
```

your code will be

```
Result.TransacDetails.Add(new TransactionStatistics()
    {
        Id = Convert.ToString(row["Id"]),,
        AssistCount = Convert.ToInt32(row["AssistCount"]),
        WaitTime = Convert.ToInt32(row["WaitTime"]),
        AverageStandardWaitTime = CalculateAverageStandardWaitTime(row)                  
    });
```

Comment: when "WaitTime":32, and AssistCount = 2 , AverageStandardWaitTime is showing as 0 can you please tell me why

Comment: @thomsan -so you have like this (32/2) / 60 => 16/60 = 0.266 value , so check datatype of AverageStandardWaitTime  is not int, it needs to be double, one more suggestion if you have created method as i given please put debug point and check you are getting proper values